# Evaluating PHP inside javascript for a wordpress blog for a pinterest button

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, wordpress, pinterest

This is a very interesting problem that I am running into. I am appending a div with a pinterest button using javaScript but I am using PHP inside the Javascript to determine what the source of the image and the URL of the page to send to pinterest.

I am doing it this way instead of using plain HTML provided by pinterest because I have found that you can use your own branded pinterst button .jpg instead of the iFrame that pinterest uses and forces you to use their branding. I have used this javaScript successfully on other parts of my sites without using PHP. I am very new to PHP and JavaScript so I am not sure if I am missing anything but I have spent countless hours tinkering with this problem and need a fresh set of eyes. Thanks for all your help!

```
function add_social_media () {
?>
<p align="right">
    <a href="http://twitter.com/home?status=<?php print(urlencode(get_permalink())); ?>+<?php print(urlencode(the_title())); ?>">
<img src="/sites/aerialist.localhost/files/images/twitter.jpg" alt="Share On Twitter" /></a>

<a href="http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=http%3A%2F%2Ffamousartistprints.com%2F&media=http%3A%2F%2Ffamousartistprints.com%2F" ><img border="0" src="/sites/aerialist.localhost/files/images/twitter.jpg"/></a>

<script>

jQuery(document).ready(function() {

   jQuery('#pinItDiv').append( '<a class="pin-it-button" href="http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url='+
          <?php the_permalink(); ?>+
          '&media='+
          //set your image path here
          <?php if(function_exists('the_post_thumbnail')) echo wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id()); ?>+
          '&description='+<?php echo get_the_title(); ?>'">'+
          '<img class="pinItSuite" title="Pin It" src="/sites/aerialist.localhost/files/images/pinSuite.jpg" alt="" border="0" /></a>');

});

</script>




<?php
}
add_action('thesis_hook_before_headline', 'add_social_media');
```

Comment: Am I blind, or I can't see anything about the problem itself? ;)

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, it's best practice to keep php and javascript separate as much as possible. Try putting your javascript in its own js file and enqueuing it with wordpress's scripts via wp_enqueue_scripts. Then use wp_localize_script to pass it any php variables you need (such as the_permalink() or get_the_title() ).

Check out these sites for more info:

http://wp.tutsplus.com/articles/how-to-include-javascript-and-css-in-your-wordpress-themes-and-plugins/

http://tosbourn.com/2011/08/wordpress/accessing-php-variables-from-within-javascript-under-wordpress/